# .aspx pages come up with "Unknown File Type" on Browser

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have exactly same issue mentioned in the forum linked below, i.e. some times when a user enters our site in a browser he gets `UnKnown File type` message with open save dialog box and when this comes it is continuous until we restart IIS.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1166056.aspx

The difference is we are using Windows 2003 and II6 so the patch mentioned in the above forum is not applicable in our case. I have tried searching the Microsoft forums, but was unable to get any relevant answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

check your pages extensions and all your files in website. One of image or page may cause that (.pnf, .aspc etc.)

Comment: Please do post the entire question in here to avoid having the question closed. You are making people to go to another thread in another site just to get your entire scenario.